# Braced initialisation of std::map member compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, list-initialization

The following code does not compile using Visual Studio 2013. It does compile  using Xcode 6.1 (Clang 3.5).

```
std::string s1("one");
std::string s2("two");
std::string s3("three");
std::string s4("four");

class X
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MyMapType;
    MyMapType map1 = { { s1, s2 }, { s3, s4 } };
    MyMapType map2 = { { std::make_pair(s1, s2) }, { std::make_pair(s3, s4) } };
};
```

The error reported for both declarations is:

```
error C2664: 'std::map<std::string,std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>::map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>,const std::less<_Ty> &,const std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'initializer-list' to 'const std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>> &'
```

However, the following does compile:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MyMapType;
    MyMapType map3 = { { s1, s2 }, { s3, s4 } };

    return 0;
}
```

Please can someone explain this.

Comment: Looks like a VC++ bug

Comment: VC2013 is known to be broken with NSDMI+list-initialization. This code compiles fine with [MS's online compiler running VS2015](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)

Comment: @T.C. My mistake. It compiles for me too using the online compiler. I didn't know that existed. Thanks.

Comment: @T.C. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I can then accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++ 2013 is known to be buggy with its handling of list initialization in non-static data member initializers and constructor member initializer lists. It was so badly broken - in some cases causing silent bad codegen - that [they simply made it a compiler error in all cases in Visual 
Studio 2013 Update 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793970.aspx) (shipping an actual fix [was apparently deemed too risky for an update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/08/19/the-future-of-non-static-data-member-initialization.aspx)).

Your code compiles fine with [Microsoft's online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), which runs a preview version of Visual C++ 2015, so it looks like this has been fixed.

A workaround (noted in the MSDN page linked above) is explicitly specifying the type on the RHS as well, so that you are not actually list-initializing the non-static data member.

```
MyMapType map1 = MyMapType{ { s1, s2 }, { s3, s4 } };
MyMapType map2 = MyMapType{ { std::make_pair(s1, s2) }, { std::make_pair(s3, s4) } };
```