# Initializing structure as map value strange behavior (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have having trouble initializing structure as map value. The first example works find with enum being the second field of the structure. However the second example doesn't compile. Can anyone please tell me why and how to fix it? I would prefer that my struct is initialized with one liner because I am going to put a lot of value in the map.

```
enum EnumA
{
   TEST
};

struct ObjectA
{
    std::string name;
    EnumA type;
}

std::map<uint8_t, ObjectA> map1= {
    { 0, { "This is a test", EnumA::TEST} }
};
```

However second one

```
struct ObjectB
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
}
std::map<uint8_t, ObjectB> map2= {
    { 0, { "This fails!!", "abc"} },
    { 1, { "This fails!!", "abc"} },
    { 2, { "This fails!!", "abc"} },
    { 3, { "This fails!!", "abc"} }
};
```

ERROR

```
C2398   Element '10': conversion from 'initializer list' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' requires a narrowing conversion
```

This seems related [Braced initialisation of std::map member compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062224/braced-initialisation-of-stdmap-member-compiler-error). It suggests that VS is bugged. But I am using VS2015 now.

Comment: 0,1,2,3 will be treated as an `int`, but you end up storing it as `uint8_t` and hence the error (I thought it was a warning, but anyways).

Comment: Thank you so much! It turns out that I was trying to store 2byte into 1 byte. I fixed it now thank you : )

Comment: Between, clang and g++ seems quite happy with it. It makes me wonder whether VS is missing some intelligence while conversion from initializer_list here.

Comment: What version of MSVS 2015 do you have?  I have version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL and it compiles fine.

Comment: I can only get that error with value that do not fit in a `uint8_t`, and I think this is standard behavior since the standard do not allow narrowing conversion in braced-list initializer (which is what you actually use for the construction of your `std::pair`s).

Comment: Your error is about `Element '10'` but you have only 4 elements in your example so I am guessing you have elements with value greater than 255 in your real code?